# Why is this jQuery selector so slow?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, performance

Based on testing a page with ~220 elements, of which ~200 are checkbox elements, and each element has to query an array with ~200 items, I was surprised to discover that [input selector](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/):

```
$("input[id$='" + code + "']").each(function() { //...
```

is approximately 4-5 times faster than

```
$("input:checkbox[id$='" + code + "']").each(function() { //...
```

and approximately 10 times faster than a [checkbox selector](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/):

```
$(":checkbox[id$='" + code + "']").each(function() { //...
```

Also tried universal selector `*`, which performed about the same as `input`.

I'm curious to understand why such a big difference in performance?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your first example is the faster because it only involves the check of the `id` attribute, on all the `input` elements.

The `input:checkbox` selector is equivalent to an [*Attribute Equals*](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) selector:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]')
```

So basically you are doing *two* attribute selectors in your second example:

```
$("input[type=checkbox][id$='" + code + "']").each(function() { //...
```

Now in your third example, since you don't specify a tag name or anything else, it will inspect all DOM elements, since the [`:checkbox`](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/) selector is equivalent to :

```
$("*:checkbox")//...
```

That's why is always recommended to precede this kind of selectors with a tag name or some other selector.

At the end, your third example (the slowest) is equivalent to something like this:

```
$("[type=checkbox][id$='" + code + "']").each(function() { //...
```

Comment: Thanks. So does each attribute selector iterate over the DOM separately?  Or does it iterate just once, but evaluation of attributes is faster because it only has to check for id (short-circuited?) instead of multiple attributes?

Comment: You could do... $('#' + code).each(function(){});
Here is a good link to JQuery Selector Performance Rules. http://www.artzstudio.com/2009/04/jquery-performance-rules/

Comment: @delux, thanks for the link, and note operator is $= so #+code won't work.